# Groovy - sorting my object list using two criterias

Tags: sorting, groovy

Following this class:

```
class Report
{
  String firstName
  String lastName
}
```

I need to sort my ***Person*** list first by the **last name** and then by the **first name**.

I tried to make it using this code:

```
persons.sort{[it.lastName, it.firstName]}
```

But it didn't managed to do so. 
Are there any other suggestions to have sorting by two criterias?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With latest version of groovy You can achieve this with [@Sortable](http://beta.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.3.0/html/documentation/#xform-Sortable) annotation.

Second option is to implement `Comparable` and use `spaceship` (`<=>`) operator.

And here's sample just with `sort` method:

```
import groovy.transform.ToString

@ToString
class R {
  def f
  def l
}

def list = [new R(f: 'A', l: 'B'),new R(f: 'A', l: 'A'),new R(f: 'A', l: 'C'),new R(f: 'B', l: 'C')]

list.sort {left, right -> left.l <=> right.l ?: left.f <=> right.f}
```